# Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host. In manifest 3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

Help me, please! I have gotten error `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url. Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.` and `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.` in google chrome manifest 3.

Listener from content script

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(req, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(req.msg === "analysis background") {
        let obj = parse();
        sendResponse(obj);
    }
        
    return true;
}
); 
);
```

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "extensionParser",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "action": { 
        "default_popup": "popups/popup.html"
      },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "scripting",
        "http://localhost/site_for_parsing"]
}
```

Code from background file

```js
const siteUrl = "http://localhost/site_for_parsing";

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
    port.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
        if(msg.message === 'analysis') {
            chrome.tabs.create({active: false, url: siteUrl}, tab => {
                chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                    target: {tabId:tab.id},
                    files: ['dist/parser.js']
                }, (results) => {
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {msg: "analysis background"}, res => {
                        port.postMessage(res)
                        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id)
                    })
                })
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Thank you in advance! I'm waiting your answers. Good day!

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried use host_permissions, but it doesn't work. I have gotten the same mistakes

Comment: What does your `parse` function do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Site permissions should be added to `host_permissions`, not `permissions`, [more info](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#host-permissions).
2. create + executeScript in ManifestV3 is [bugged](https://crbug.com/1191971) in Chrome older than 100 so either a) go back to ManifestV2 until Chrome 100 is stable or b) use the workaround below.

**Wait for the URL to be set**:

```js
(async () => {
  const tab = await chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://www.example.com'});
  const tabId = tab.id;
  if (!tab.url) await onTabUrlUpdated(tabId);
  const results = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId},
    files: ['content.js'],
  });
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {msg: 'analysis background'}, res => {
    port.postMessage(res);
    chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
  });
})();

function onTabUrlUpdated(tabId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const onUpdated = (id, info) => id === tabId && info.url && done(true);
    const onRemoved = id => id === tabId && done(false);
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onUpdated);
    chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(onRemoved);
    function done(ok) {
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onUpdated);
      chrome.tabs.onRemoved.removeListener(onRemoved);
      (ok ? resolve : reject)();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Which way do you recommend?

Comment: It depends on whether you are willing to spend your time on the migration to ManifestV3 which is still full of bugs all around.

Comment: @wOxxOm potentially dumb question, but can I just switch from v3 to v2 and everything should still work? I'm on mobile so I can't try just yet, but I don't know why I didn't think about downgrading and so I'm curious if that's something thats supported (i.e. any valid v3 configuration will also work in v2)

Comment: It depends. If you encounter problems, post a new question with a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: thank you @wOxxOm it saved me so much time. I didn't expect new manifest would be so buggy.